# Comprehensive security solution for ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-2

If you were planning and preparing for a big ASP.NET MVC project how would you approach it to design and build comprehensive, extensible and maintainable security solution that requires

- users,
- roles,
- controller-level and action-level security,
- item-level security (applying users or roles to items),
- security trimming (hiding some menu options based on the above settings).

If you were to estimate the time and effort to produce this and would have to issue a qoute to the client, what would it be? You don't have to give a number in money, only billable hours.

Comment: Read this book: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-ASP-NET-Security-Wrox-Programmer/dp/0470743654.

Comment: This question requires an indepth analysis and good design upfront, which I don't think I will get if I read this book because as it seems it is a general, all around overview of security related questions. And it also lacks MVC aspects of security.

Answer (score 3):

> You don't have to give a number in money, only billable hours.

You want someone to do your work for free? Come on...

### Authorization

Anyway, I would use Code Access Security and impersonation to implement security in all my services. Check the [PrinicpalPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission.aspx) attribute.

**Controller/Action level**

As for MVC, simply use the [Authorize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute to provide authorization. Derive it to provide a more finegrained control.

**Security trimming**

```
if (System.Thread.Threading.CurrentThread.CurrentPricinpal.IsInRole("Administrator"))
   //show menu item
```

**Item level**

Not possible with default MVC implementation. You need to do a manual check in your actions.

```
if (!System.Thread.Threading.CurrentThread.CurrentPricinpal.IsInRole(item.RequiredRole))
  return View("AccessDenied", null); //return accessdenied view.
```

### Authentication

I don't know what kind of users you got. Are all registered in a AD domain? Then use Windows Authentication to authenticate your users. It's just a IIS setting..